# How do I set up PreAuthenticationAuthenticationProvider?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I've been trying to get OAuth 2 working for my application but I continue running into configuration-related errors, specifically involving authentication tokens. The application is set up to act as both authorization and resource server. I've successfully configured it to issue tokens using password grant type, with an in-memory token store. However, every time I try to send requests for restricted resources, I get errors saying:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken
```

So, I tried setting up a `PreAuthenticationAuthenticationProvider` in my configuration:

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsManager userManager;

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider preAuthenticationAuthenticationProvider() {
    PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider =
        new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
    UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper userDetailsWrapper = new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper(userManager);
    authenticationProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(userDetailsWrapper);
    return authenticationProvider;
}
```

However, I'm getting `NullPointerException` in weird places, like:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker.check(AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker.java:17) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
```

I'm wondering what the simplest configuration for this is, and why I need it in the first place? Is it because I have `@PreAuthorize` annotations?

Here's how I set up the resource server:

```
@Configuration
protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //http configuration
    }

}
```

The `TokenStore` is just an instance of `InMemoryTokenStore` and `AuthenticationManager` is set up this way:

```
@Configuration
protected static class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    protected UserDetailsManager userManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(preAuthenticationAuthenticationProvider())
                .userDetailsService(userManager).passwordEncoder(PASSWORD_ENCODER);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationProvider preAuthenticationAuthenticationProvider() {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider =
                new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
        UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper userDetailsWrapper = new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper(userManager);
        authenticationProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(userDetailsWrapper);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what weird places mean? How have you configured your auth server and resource server?

Comment: I've updated the question with some lines from the the stacktrace.

Comment: The authentication provider does not seem to be wired properly into your authentication manager. Are you using annotation based configuration or xml? Can you share the security configurations of your resource server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was missing are `AuthorizationServiceTokenServices` and `ResourceServerTokenServices`. Both these interfaces are implmented by Spring's `DefaultTokenServices`.

```
@Bean
public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
    DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    tokenServices.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    return tokenServices;
}
```

In the authorization server configuration (`AuthorizationServiceConfigurerAdapter`), I have the following setup:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.tokenServices(tokenServices()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
```

In the resource server configuration (`ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`):

```
@Autowired
private DefaultTokenServices tokenServices;

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.tokenServices(tokenServices);
}
```

With all these components, my app works without any `PreAuthenticationAuthenticationProvider` bean defined.